# Telethon python keeps re-downloading photos

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I've been scratching my head for the past half hour, but I can't fix this error, let me explain.
Basically what I'm trying to do is to make a simple script that will download both texts and photos from the last 6 days, the script works fine in everything except that when I re-run it, it will download again photos ending up with duplicated images.

This is the code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from telethon import TelegramClient


date = datetime.now() + timedelta(-6)
api_id =  123
api_hash = 'XXX'
client = TelegramClient('SESSION', api_id, api_hash)

#Blank files have been already created
async def main():
    with open("downloadedids.txt", "r+") as archivio, open("messagesaved.txt", "r+") as scaricare:
        async for message in client.iter_messages('test', offset_date=date, reverse=True): ##I want to download only messages 6 days ago to now
            if str(message.id) not in str(archivio.read()):
                if (message.photo):
                    await message.download_media("Include")
                scaricare.write(str(message.text))
                archivio.write(str(message.id) + "\n")


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Maybe the problem is related to async?

Comment: If you don't specify a path where the file should be downloaded, Telethon will automatically generate a new one. If this is the case, it will not overwrite files as you could lose data. Instead, it makes sure the new filename is unique. Tell it the filename to use and you will stop getting duplicates.

Comment: Still doesn't work, i tried doing something like: await message.download_media(r"folder\filename" + str(message.id)) but when I re-run it, I get a duplicate photo, for example filename3300.png and then filename3300 (1).png

Comment: You also have to provide the extension, otherwise it is still generating a name (adding the extension and making sure it doesn't overwrite). You can get this with `m.file.ext`.

Comment: Now it works, however I noticed that execution time is the same as if the photos were re-downloaded and replaced, since I am doing this check:             if str(message.id) not in str(archivio.read()): it shouldn't even try to download a new photo...

Comment: It's intended behaviour. If you pass a explicit filename, it will download to it, even overwriting files if needed. Just check it doesn' exist in your code and avoid download.

Answer (score 1):

It's downloading it again because you are telling it to! Perhaps you want to do a checksum on the existing file and if it matches, don't keep the second one?

Comment: Let's say that I downloaded messages and photos and I have saved their ID in the downloadedids.txt file, the next time I run the script this conditional check:    ``` if str(message.id) not in str(archivio.read()): ``` should avoid re-downloading photos.

Comment: @jimmy23x well yes, that would work. There are probably better ways but that is simple and should work